# Laptop recommendation for LaTeX

Tags: performance

so I am trying to get a **laptop (or tablet, any portable device**) that will be almost **solely used for LaTeX**.

My highest priority are **weight**, **battery life**, and then **cost**,
which I think could bring down quite a lot because LaTeX shouldn't be that heavy of a task. I know this is not necessarily a question about writing in LaTeX, but is there anyone who'd be able to give recommendations?

The ones that I have thought of up til now is Windows surface pro and Chromebook, installing Ubuntu on it. Windows surface RT had good cost, but I don't think I have enough CS knowledge to deal with the procedures afterwards.

Comment: This is not about (La)TeX... And, as far as I'm considered, most laptops would do; midrange ones included.

Comment: The modern versions of LaTeX has been running on every computer since the 80s so it doesn't matter. Plus this is both off-topic and a shopping-list question hence I agree with Werner.

Comment: Off-topic, I think.  The hard part is finding a laptop that is light enough and good on battery life, not whether *TeX will run on it.  But, for what it's worth, I recently bought a Macbook Air (11") for weight and battery reasons (wish it had been cheaper, but the battery life and weight are great) installed Ubuntu on it, and run LaTeX all the time on it.  It's the only computer I use....

Comment: If you are making documents with lots of TiKZ diagrams, or hundreds of pages, *and* you frequently recompile your document, performance is an issue. Otherwise, you do not need any very powerful laptop. Buy a laptop based on the screen size, keyboard, and Linux compatibility.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103565/15925

Comment: Not sure whether I should delete the question or keep it at this point.

Comment: Keep it, it does no harm and gives another link to andrews linked post. That way google can find it easier ;-)

Comment: What Niel said +1. Does not look like off topic for me. I would get something running XP (if you still can), and look at the higher MHz rather than lots of RAM and HDD.

Comment: This may be relevant [Tips for choosing hardware for best LaTeX compile performance](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103565/tips-for-choosing-hardware-for-best-latex-compile-performance)

Comment: Jack, that was the link Andrew gave above, but thank you for recommending it again!