# Reducing the document preparation time with lualatex

Tags: tables, luatex, pdf, lua, rendering

I am trying to render a document that is around 2300 pages from a JSON file using `lualatex`.

It takes around 32 seconds to create a document. The document is a series of tables and paragraphs. I think that 32 seconds is slow and I am hoping if I could reduce the total time to prepare the document to 16 seconds for the same number of pages.

I did all my initial experiments with `pdflatex` and had found the rendering to be much faster. But since the document has to be dynamically generated where the length of the document could be anywhere between 20 - 5000 pages, I decided to use `lualatex`.

I will explain what all I have done, and what all is generated.

Here is the JSON ([beautified JSON for easier viewing](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb8e0d5a)) from which the document is rendered. I have greatly reduced the size of JSON for this question. But you could imagine many more *sections* and *subsections* inside `tableOfContents`.

```
    {
     "documentName": "AA",
     "author": "BB",
     "documentId": "MAC-FF/1",
     "documentGeneratedAt": "BB",
     "documentGeneratedBy": "FF",
     "macProtocolID": "CV/1",
     "version": "1",
     "headerFooter": {
     "header": {
          "left": "LFT",
          "right": "RT"
      },
      "footer": {
          "left": "F/1"
       }
     },
    "tableOfContents": [
        {
              "section": {
                  "title": "Actives Limit Calculations",
                  "text": "This is section text"
              },
              "subsection": [
                  {
                    "id": "Pr1",
                    "title": "Febuxostat Tablets 40 mg 80 mg and 120 mg (Pr1)",
                    "content": [
                      {
                        "type": "text",
                        "line": "Worst SAL: 0.725 mg/sqcm"
                      },
                      {
                        "type": "text",
                        "line": "Next Production: Dabigatran Etexilate Capsules 75 mg 110 mg and 150 mg (Pr2)"
                      },
                      {
                        "type": "text",
                        "line": "Next PSwab Limit: 1813.458 ppm Swab Area: 25 sqcm Swab Volume: 10 ml"
                      },
                      {
                        "type": "table",
                        "title": "",
                        "columns": [
                          {
                            "name": "Previous API(A)",
                            "values": [
                              "1",
                              "2",
                              "3",
                              "4"
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "Next Production",
                            "values": [
                              "Pr1",
                              "Pr2",
                              "Pr3",
                              "Pr4"
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "ID (B)",
                            "values": [
                              "Pr1",
                              "Pr2",
                              "Pr3",
                              "Pr4"
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
              ]
        }
    ]
}
```

To prepare a document from the above JSON, I read the JSON and then iterate over to prepare the document inside `\luacode`. Here is how I am doing this.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
    \usepackage{luacode}
    \begin{luacode}
    local socket = require("socket")
    local json = require("json")
    local file = io.open("sample.json")
    local start = socket.gettime()
    tab = json.parse(file:read("*all"))
    texio.write_nl("Time passed parsing JSON: " .. socket.gettime() - start .. " s\string\n")
    file:close()
    \end{luacode}

    \begin{luacode}
    local function isempty(s)
    return s == nil or s == ''
    end

    function renderSections(tab)
        for i,k in pairs(tab['tableOfContents']) do
            local sec_start = socket.gettime()
            tex.print ("\string\\section{" .. k.section.title .. "}")
            tex.print("section text here")
            for ii,kk in pairs(k["subsection"]) do
                tex.print ("\string\\subsection{" .. kk.title .. "}")
                tex.print ("some text here")
                tex.print("\string\\newline")
                for iii, kkk in pairs(kk["content"]) do
                    if kkk['type'] == "text" then
                        tex.print(kkk["line"])
                        tex.print("\string\\newline")
                    elseif kkk["type"] == "table" then
                        local column_count = 0
                        local row_count = 0
                        col_schema = ""
                        for _ in pairs(kkk["columns"]) do 
                            column_count = column_count + 1 
                            col_schema = col_schema .. " | l"
                        end
                        col_schema = col_schema .. "|"
                        for _ in pairs(kkk["columns"][1]["values"]) do row_count = row_count + 1 end
                        if not isempty(kkk.title) then
                            tex.print("\string\\textbf{" .. kkk.title .."}")
                            tex.print("\\\\[0.1in]")
                        end
                        tex.print("\string\\begin{tabular}{"  .. col_schema ..  "}")
                        tex.print("\\hline")
                        for ci, c in pairs(kkk["columns"]) do
                            tex.print(c.name)
                            if ci < column_count then
                                tex.print(" & ")
                            end
                        end 
                        tex.print("\\\\")
                        tex.print("\\hline")
                        i = 1
                        while i <= row_count do
                            local c_c = 1
                            while c_c <= column_count do
                                tex.print(kkk["columns"][c_c]["values"][i])
                                if c_c < column_count then
                                    tex.print(" & ")
                                end
                                c_c = c_c + 1
                            end
                            tex.print("\\\\")
                            tex.print("\\hline")
                            i = i + 1
                        end
                        tex.print("\string\\end{tabular}")
                        tex.print("\\\\[0.1in]")
                    end
                end
            end
            texio.write_nl("Time passed rendering section: " .. socket.gettime() - sec_start .. " s\string\n")
        end
    end
    \end{luacode}

    \title{\directlua{tex.print(tab['documentName'])}}
    \author{\directlua{tex.print(tab['author'])}}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{pgffor}
    \usepackage{lastpage}
    %\usepackage[extreme]{savetrees}
    \usepackage[landscape, margin=1in]{geometry}
    \usepackage[yyyymmdd,hhmmss]{datetime}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks=true,
        linkcolor=blue,
        filecolor=magenta,      
        urlcolor=cyan,
        pdftitle={AAA Report},
        bookmarks=true,
        pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
    }
    % https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors
    \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}


    \lhead{\directlua{tex.print(tab['headerFooter']['header']['left'])}}
    \rhead{\directlua{tex.print(tab['headerFooter']['header']['right'])}}
    \lfoot{\directlua{tex.print(tab['headerFooter']['footer']['left'])}}
    \rfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
    \cfoot{}
    \renewcommand*\contentsname{TABLE OF CONTENTS}


    \begin{document}
    \maketitle


    \paragraph{Document Information}

    \subparagraph{Document information is given in the table below}

    \subparagraph{}
    \begin{tabular}{|c| c| c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{S.No} & \textbf{Item} & \textbf{Information} \\
    \hline
    1 & Document ID & \directlua{tex.print(tab['documentId'])} \\
    \hline
    2 & Document Generated At & \directlua{tex.print(tab['documentGeneratedAt'])} \\
    \hline  
    3 & Document Generated By & \directlua{tex.print(tab['documentGeneratedBy'])} \\
    \hline
    4 & AAA Protocol ID & \directlua{tex.print(tab['macProtocolID'])} \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    %\newpage
    %\textcolor{NavyBlue}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
    \tableofcontents
    \directlua{renderSections(tab)}

    \end{document}
```

Here is also the helper `json.lua` (in the same directory) which the above code uses to read the JSON file.

```
local lpeg = assert(require("lpeg"))
local C, Cf, Cg, Ct, P, R, S, V =
    lpeg.C, lpeg.Cf, lpeg.Cg, lpeg.Ct, lpeg.P, lpeg.R, lpeg.S, lpeg.V

-- number parsing
local digit    = R"09"
local dot      = P"."
local eE       = S"eE"
local sign     = S"+-"^-1
local mantissa = digit^1 * dot * digit^0 + dot * digit^1 + digit^1
local exponent = (eE * sign * digit^1)^-1
local real     = sign * mantissa * exponent / tonumber

-- optional whitespace
local ws = S" \t\n\r"^0

-- match a literal string surrounded by whitespace
local lit = function(str)
    return ws * P(str) * ws
end

-- match a literal string and synthesize an attribute
local attr = function(str,attr)
    return ws * P(str) / function() return attr end * ws
end

-- JSON grammar
local json = P{
    "object",

    value =
        V"null_value" +
        V"bool_value" +
        V"string_value" +
        V"real_value" +
        V"array" +
        V"object",

    null_value =
        attr("null", nil),

    bool_value =
        attr("true", true) + attr("false", false),

    string_value =
        ws * P'"' * C((P'\\"' + 1 - P'"')^0) * P'"' * ws,

    real_value =
        ws * real * ws,

    array =
        lit"[" * Ct((V"value" * lit","^-1)^0) * lit"]",

    member_pair =
        Cg(V"string_value" * lit":" * V"value") * lit","^-1,

    object =
        lit"{" * Cf(Ct"" * V"member_pair"^0, rawset) * lit"}"
}

return { parse = function(str) return assert(json:match(str)) end }
```

I also did some profiling:

- Reading JSON takes *less than a second*
- Rendering a section and subsection from `tex.print ("\string\\section{" .. k.section.title .. "}")` takes *~1 microsecond*

I want to understand where is the time being lost. What could I do to reduce the rendering time? Is there a better way to structure my latex that might help reduce the total preparation time?

Comment: You could put in the document some timer code to benchmark (see e.g. https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50073473#50073473) or with l3benchmark https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/463558/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, have done that in `renderSections` function and section that parses the `JSON`

Comment: My machine reports `Time passed parsing JSON: 9.2983245849609e-05 s` and `Time passed rendering section: 2.1934509277344e-05 s`.  There is hardly any room to optimize this.  BTW, for rendering the section you are only profiling the Lua time, not the TeX time.

Comment: @HenriMenke For a 7MB JSON file that I tried with time spent parsing was 0.22 seconds. As I also mentioned in the question, that is not an issue. So should I prefix every latex command with `\benchmark`?

Comment: Alternatively, you can try to parse the JSON outside of LaTeX (with Perl, Python, standalone Lua), generate the corresponding LaTeX source and write to a file, and run `pdflatex` on it. The file I/O will take extra time, but you could use a memory-based filesystem for that (like `tmpfs`) or an SSD. But then again, is 30 seconds for 2300 pages really such a long time? Unless you do this very often (every five minutes or so), but in that case you might be able to reduce the frequency somewhere else in your workflow.

Comment: I doubt that the json parsing is the bottleneck, the tex rendering is normally slower than the lua so you should benchmark this. Which texsystem do you use?