# Why use xfp rather than fp?

Tags: latex3

I use fp a lot. What is the point of modifying all the code? 
I prefer the syntax of xfp but is this a sufficient argument? 
You are going to say that `\fpeval` is expandable but what is the example 
 that can tilt the balance in favour of xfp ?
Maybe a Tag xfp would be useful ?

**Update**

After reading the comments and reading the linked documents, I specify what I am looking for :

1. Speed : It's not a really argument for me, when we use TeX for calculations and geometric drawings I think we can wait a bit for a result.
2. Functionality it's important
3. Technical considerations (particularly expandability)

Do you have examples (with fp and xfp) that show that one is more functional than the other, or that xfp is expandable is a major asset or that not being expandable is sometimes useful?

Comment: I think one nontrivial example in which expandability is an advantage is when you use it in `pstricks` coordinates, which do not get parsed. Otherwise you'd have to define tons of macros for each component that is to be parsed. (Let's not discuss why one would still want to use pstricks. ;-) There are many additional examples where `\numexpr` does not suffice because it basically only works with integers. Of course, if you use Ti*k*Z the advantage is much less pronounced since you can just define a function that uses `fp` and gets parsed wherever needed, as you know very well.

Comment: https://www.texdev.net/2018/12/09/floating-point-calculations-in-latex and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463554/known-benchmarks-for-floating-point-calculations

Comment: another advantage, if you are using latex-dev (or latex from 2020-02-02) is that expl3 (so all the code behind xfp) is loaded in the format,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I would love to see your time machine. :)

Comment: @frougon you can see it now, type `latex-dev '\stop'` into a terminal:-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I do not see how these comparisons really answer the question. It is good to have them, yes, but does this answer the question?

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat that's why I "only" commented. (But the fact that fp is slow and that you can't use it where a number is expected is quite important for me).

Comment: @frougon no timemachine involved, read https://www.latex-project.org/news/2019/09/01/LaTeX-dev-format/ to learn about -dev formats

Comment: @FrankMittelbach I just try `lualatex-dev` to compile 170 pages of my new documentation with 200 pictures, it's fine !!

Comment: @AlainMatthes good to hear, please continue doing these kind of tests and watch the news feed on the website, there will be another -dev version in a couple of days