# On the xfp package: Comparison

Tags: ifthenelse, xfp

On page 1/2 of the [xfp package](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xfp.pdf) we read:

- The floating point expressions may comprise:Comparison operators: x < y, x <= y, x >? y, x ! = y etc.
  However they did not show an example. Below I have an example in which I use `\fpeval{\x<\y }` to make a decision in a conditional command:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{xfp, ifthen}
  \begin{document}
  \edef\x{6.25}
  \edef\y{-2}
  \noindent $x=\fpeval{\x}$.\\
   $y=\fpeval{\y}$.\\
  \ifthenelse{\fpeval{\x<\y }}
   {$x\lt y$}
   {$x\ge y$}
   \end{document}
  ```

But got an error:

> ! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
>
> \relax
> l.10 \ifthenelse{\fpeval{\x<\y }}

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I think `\fpeval` is supposed to evaluate to a number. I don't know the full rules, but I'd guess it's 1 if the test is true and 0 otherwise. In that case you'd want `\ifthenelse{\fpeval{\x<\y }=1}`. If it's 0 if the test is false and non-zero otherwise, you'd probably want to go for `\ifthenelse{\fpeval{\x<\y }=0}` and invert the logic.

Comment: Great Answer!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: @moewe would you please write ur answer below then I accept it?

Comment: related [Why use xfp rather than fp?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/522855/138900)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `\ifthenelse` must contain a test (by default a test on integer equality).

You could do `\ifthenelse{\fpeval{\x<\y}=1}{...}{...}` which would return true if `\x` is actually less than `\y`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp,ifthen}

\begin{document}

\def\x{6.25}
\def\y{-2}

\ifthenelse{\fpeval{\x<\y}=1}{TRUE}{FALSE} (should be F)

\ifthenelse{\fpeval{\y<\x}=1}{TRUE}{FALSE} (should be T)

\end{document}
```

[image]

With more flexible (and fully expandable) code that I already suggested you

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp,xparse}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\xifthenelse}{mmm}
 {
  \bool_if:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_eq:NN \numtest     \int_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \oddtest     \int_if_odd_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \fptest      \fp_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \dimtest     \dim_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \deftest     \cs_if_exist_p:N
\cs_new_eq:NN \namedeftest \cs_if_exist_p:c
\cs_new_eq:NN \eqdeftest   \token_if_eq_meaning_p:NN
\cs_new_eq:NN \streqtest   \str_if_eq_p:ee
\cs_new_eq:NN \emptytest   \tl_if_blank_p:n
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \xxifthen_legacy_conditional:n { p,T,F,TF }
 {
  \use:c { if#1 } \prg_return_true: \else: \prg_return_false: \fi:
 }
\cs_new_eq:NN \boolean \xxifthen_legacy_conditional_p:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\def\x{6.25}
\def\y{-2}

\xifthenelse{\fptest{\x<\y}}{TRUE}{FALSE} (should be F)

\xifthenelse{\fptest{\y<\x}}{TRUE}{FALSE} (should be T)

\end{document}
```