# pgfplots: Strange Bump in `\tanh` Function

Tags: pgfplots, pgfmath

**Follow up question** see [pgfplots: x vs \x](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611793).

---

I have a rather straightforward `pgfplots` diagram but I do not understand why there is a **bump** in my `tanh` function (should be smooth). The `domain` (and `samples`) key seems to influence the outcome. Can you explain this behavior and is there a systematic logic to prevent that (or do I need to use a trial-and-error approach)?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} % Updated after comments, was 1.15 before.

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width = 160mm,
        height = 90mm,
        axis lines = center,
        xmin = -10,
        xmax = 10,
        ymin = -1,
        ymax = 1,
        enlarge x limits = 0.05,
        enlarge y limits = 0.10,
        ]
    \addplot[
        color = blue,
        mark = none,
        smooth,
        line width = 1pt,
        domain = -30:30, % When changed to -10:10 then the bump is not visible.
        samples = 200,
        ] {tanh(1*\x)};     
        %       
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If changing the domain to -10:10 fixes it, why not?

Comment: @JohnKormylo My question is more about the "why" :).

Comment: Getting rid of the compati=1.15 also fixes it, so this is probably a bug which has already been fixed.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks. That is good advice.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Just tested, with `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}` the problem still remains. I have updated the code accordingly. Thanks for the new "problem variable".

Comment: New bug?  Interesting!  I would just chalk it up to the poor dancing bear having problems.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I am not a native speaker and have to google the meaning of "I would just chalk it up to the poor dancing bear having problems" :).

Comment: Must be fpu's problem. I see `tanh(6.656) = 1Y1.2e0]`.

Comment: I manage to boil this down to (without fpu) \pgfmathdivide@{38.87068}{38.8708}\pgfmathresult = 1.2. Note that the numerator is smaller than the denominator yet the result is > 1.

Comment: You can't expect accuracy from pgfmath.  (The amazing thing about a dancing bear is that it dances at all.)  For accuracy, do you calculations using Matlab etc. and store the data in a pgfplots compatible table.

Comment: Also note that the Lua backend is *only for pgfplots*, as far as I can see it's impossible to switch other parts of TikZ to use Lua.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Symbol 1 shows in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/611595/95441) the root cause of the problem. Maybe missing is the information, that all this (only) happens, when *TeX* is used as calculation engine. Since Symbol 1 has no idea how to fix this (in TeX) (of course this is no offense) the "fix" is to use another calculation engine ... ;)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.18.1
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfmath-xfp}
    % define `tanh` function
    \pgfmxfpdeclarefunction{Tanh}{1}{1 - 2/(exp(2*#1) + 1)}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    % use this `compat` level or higher to use Lua as calculation engine
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        domain = 6:7,
        samples = 200,
        no markers,
    ]
        % use TeX as calculation engine
        \addplot {tanh(\x)};
        % use Lua as calculation engine (when compiled with LuaLaTeX of course)
        % (when you compile with pdfLaTeX or use a lower `compat` level than given
        %  in the preamble, this is equivalent to the previous `\addplot`)
        \addplot+ [very thick] {tanh(x)};
        % use xfp as calculation engine
        \addplot+ [thick] {Tanh(x)};
        % use gnuplot as calculation engine
        % (assuming gnuplot is installed, available and it is compiled with
        %  `shell-escape` enabled)
        \addplot gnuplot {tanh(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: +1: Is there a difference in using tanh(\x) vs tanh(x)? I was not aware of that if that's the case.

Comment: Could tanh be made a default function within pgfmath-xfp?

Comment: My thought also was that `tanh(\x)` is the same as `tanh(x)` but it seems that Lua "doesn't like" "commands", i.e. `\<something`. But to my experience I never used `\x` in `\addplot` calls. Since this is easier to read and easier to type ... But maybe @Symbol1 also has an idea here ;)

Comment: Then I think you have to ask the author of the package. But as I understand that it is just a wrapper to make it easy to use the `xfp` package. So I guess you have to ask the LaTeX3 team if they are willing to add it to `xfp`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comments. Maybe I ask a question about \x and x, unless I find an explanation in the pgfplots manual.

Comment: FYI: I posted a follow-up question, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611793.

Comment: Isn't your definition of Tanh false? At x=0, you obtain infinity. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions#Exponential_definitions I would use `\pgfmxfpdeclarefunction{Tanh}{1}{(exp(2*#1) -1)/(exp(2*#1) +1)}`. But perhaps your definition is very near the real tanh for x between 6 and 7 and faster to calculate?

Comment: @quark67, according to the [German Wiki](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tangens_hyperbolicus_und_Kotangens_hyperbolicus&oldid=213488962#Definitionen) and [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28exp%282*x%29+-1%29%2F%28exp%282*x%29+%2B1%29) "your" and "my" definition are equal ...

Comment: No, at denominator, you have a minus sign (`(exp(2*#1) -1)`), it must be a plus sign. With your minus sign, at 0 you obtain infinity. You must obtain 0.

Comment: @quark67, you are right, I corrected that, but that doesn't change the output shown in the graph.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, just FYI, I created a follow-up question about the x vs \x topic: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611793.

Answer (score 41):

tanh is defined to be sinh/cosh.
And the unexpected spike is a result of a bug in the division routine.
More precisely, the macro `\pgfmathdivide@@` defined in
`pgfmathfunctions.basic.code` line 10 ([github link](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/master/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex#L105-L176))
contains an unwanted behavior.

### `\pgfmathdivide@@`

This macro uses `\pgfmath@x` (numerator) and `\pgfmath@y` (denominator)
to implement long division.
Here is the pseudo code

```
While (x > δ & y > δ):
    If x < y:
        append and `0` at the end of \pgfmathresult;
        divide y by 10;
    Else: %%% x ≥ y
        compute a:= floor(x/y);
        If a is single digit:
            append that digit at the end of \pgfmathresult;
            subtract y by x * a
        Else: %%% in this case we always have 10 ≤ a < 20
            subtract a by 10
            depending on how many digits \pgfmathresult has, add 10^-d to \pgfmathresult
            append a to the end of \pgfmathresult
```

You see that the code becomes nasty when x/y ≥ 10.
Usually, you would expected that x/y is always less than 10
because the previous y (the y before it was divided by 10)
is less than x and the single-digit branch will be executed.
So this branch is never executed;
it doesn't matter if the code is ugly.
But that is not true.

### What could go wrong?

Thanks to finite precision, the following could happen

- (x, y) = (0.00037, 0.00038) so the x < y branch is executed;
  y is divided by 10.
- now (x, y) = (0.00037, 0.00003) so the x > y branch is executed;
  now floor(x/y) = 12 ≥ 10

"Fine," you might say.
Since 0.00038 -> 0.00003 only happens when
`\pgfmathresult` already has many digits,
adding 0.000012 or 0.00009 doesn't really matter.
Except that it sometimes does.

You see, adding 10^-d to `\pgfmathresult` isn't an easy job
because 0.001 + 0.999 includes carrying.
So instead of textually manipulating `\pgfmathresult`,
this is done by

- converting `\pgfmathresult` to a TeX dimension (`\pgfmath@xa`),
- adding `1pt`, `0.1pt`, ..., or `0.00001pt`,
- and then converting TeX dimension back to text.

The problem is, if `\pgfmathresult` is 0.99999,
then the result of adding 0.00001pt to 0.99999pt is 1pt, not 1.00000pt.
Recall that we are in the a ≥ 10 branch
and we will append a - 10 at the end of the new `\pgfmathresult`.
So if a = 12, we will get 1.2 as the result, not 1.000002.

### Fix

I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this exceptionally great answer! I wait a bit before accepting to see if there are other answers.

Comment: I will call you Sherlock Holmes from now on. :)

Comment: Remark: this bug is easy to trigger if you know what you are looking for. For instance `38.89993/38.9=1.2` and `38.8999/38.9=1.1`

Comment: If 1pt, then 1+.000001?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner To Sherlock Holmes  i give my upvoted. :-)

Comment: @Cicada: That's one way. But I can't say I like the current implementation. Turning dimensions to counters (ie treat them as `⟨integer⟩sp`) and doing integer division there seems relative simple. There is no need to overengineer the last digits as we already have 5 significant digits.

Comment: Is it ok to accept Stefan's answer instead? Your answer clearly was more effort, I see that.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Sure! No pressure =)

Comment: This reminds me (somewhat) of Scientific Computing SE's [What algorithm does (or did?) Excel use for Bessel functions that is discontinuous at x=8?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/30279/17869) (currently unanswered but some helpful comments)

Comment: FYI: I posted a follow-up question, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611793.

Comment: 26 upvotes, nice!