# pgfplots: x vs \x

Tags: pgfplots, pgfmath

- This question is a follow-up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611573)  (*"pgfplots: Strange Bump in `\tanh` Function"*).
- [Stefan Pinnow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/95441/stefan-pinnow), who knows a thing or two about `pgfplots`, provided an answer that distinguished between `\addplot{tanh(\x)};` and `\addplot{tanh(x)};`(`x` vs `\x` as the argument).
- In a comment, Stefan stated *"My thought also was that tanh(\x) is the same as tanh(x) but it seems that Lua "doesn't like" "commands", i.e. `\<something>`. But to my experience I never used \x in \addplot calls. Since this is easier to read and easier to type [...]*".

  ```
   % use TeX as calculation engine
   \addplot {tanh(\x)};
   % use Lua as calculation engine (when compiled with LuaLaTeX of course)
   \addplot+ [very thick] {tanh(x)};
  ```
- The current [`pgfplots` manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) (Revision 1.18.1 (2021/05/15)) states in Chapter 4.3.3 (Computing Coordinates with Mathematical Expressions): *"In short: it is the same whether you write \x or just x inside of math expressions."*.

[image]

- **Question:** In what circumstances does it matter whether I use `x` or `\x` in an `addplot` argument?

Comment: My understanding of this (which can be very wrong) is that with `\x` you are just passing the number literal such as `3.4567` to the function. TeX's macro expansion will do the job for you. But with `x` it undergoes some heavy csname-tricks because how in the world does PGF going to recognize a variable/function?

Comment: There was a period of time where Ti*k*Z learners use `\draw plot ...;` and it's impossible not to mess up `sin(x)` vs `sin(\x)` vs `\sin(x)` vs `\sin(\x)`. Perhaps pgfplots's author is just tired of this and try to make the interface as friendly as possible. I myself always use `sin(\x)` because I like to see it as a `\foreach\x in{...}` thing.

Comment: But now comes Lua and it powerful math engine. What do you want to do? You want to send Lua a clean string `sin(x)` instead of any variant that contains escape character ```\```. In that regard, `sin(x)` makes more sense. But of course, these are just pure guesses. I never work with lualatex because `fontspec` always fail =(

Comment: @Symbol1 Thanks for your comments! I was surprised that even Stefan had to guess :).

Comment: There may be other cases I don't know of (so not a complete answer), but at least one case is when Lua back end is used (note in chapter 6.3.1 [Reducing typesetting time → Lua]: "math expressions which involve macro definitions are unavailable in lua backend. Best practice: prefer declare function over macro constants" – The example after that shows the issue exactly.

Comment: Here is an example where ```x``` and ```\x``` don't behave the same: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/663296/strange-syntax-in-pgfplot I think this may be a bug or at least a strange behavior...

Comment: @HérissonDidier I opened a bounty in your honor :).

Comment: And the answers to my question ended by: if \x and x don't behave the same, there is a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understand, this only matters when you want to use the `lua backend`. Section 6.3.1 (*Reducing Typesetting Time* -- *LUA*) of the `pgfplots` manual explains:

> Math expressions which involve macro definitions are unavailable in `lua backend`. Best practice: prefer `declare function` over macro constants

This does not only apply to variables/functions you define yourself, but to those defined by `pgfplots`, too. `\x` is a macro which "disables" the `lua backend` for that `\addplot` and the numerically inferior TeX routines are used. `x` on the other hand is defined using (an equivalent of) `declare function`, so the `lua backend` can handle it.

If you don't use LuaTeX (or set `lua backend` to `false`), the TeX backend is always used and `\x` and `x` behave identically.

---

An MWE to illustrate the difference (compile using LuaLaTeX):

```latex
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

%\pgfplotsset{lua backend=false}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[domain=6:8] {tanh(\x) - 1};     
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[domain=6:8] {tanh(x) - 1};     
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Numerical inacurracies of the TeX backend lead to unexpected results in the first plot (using `\x`) that are not present in the second one (using `x`) which is calculated by the `lua backend`. Compiling with pdfLaTeX instead of LuaLaTeX or disabling the `lua backend` (by uncommenting the appropriate line) will lead to the second plot becoming identical to the first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So does your answer apply if I use pdflatex?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner It does: If you use `pdflatex` the `lua backend` will never be active, so `\x` and `x` should always behave identically.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I added an MWE you can play around with to see when `lua backend` is used and when it isn't.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot!