# Strange syntax in pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, pgfmath

I want to display propagation of a signal, obtained as addition of 2.
It works as I want writing:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
       \tikzmath{
       \omm=0;
       \omM=10;
       % sin sur une période, 0 sinon
       function sina(\x) {
        if and(\x>0,\x<1) then { 
       return sin(360*\x);}
        else {return 0;};};
       % fréquence double
       function sinb(\x) {
        if and(\x>0,\x<1) then { 
       return sin(720*\x);}
        else {return 0;};};
       }
       
       \begin{axis}[width=.8\columnwidth,
       height=5cm,
       xmin=\omm,
       xmax=\omM,
       axis y line=left,
       ylabel= \textcolor{blue}{Amplitude},
       xlabel= position,
        smooth,
       ]
       \addplot+[blue,thin, mark=none, samples=200,domain = \omm:\omM] {sina(x)};
       \addplot+[blue,thin, dashed, mark=none, samples=200,domain = \omm:\omM] {sinb(x)};
       \addplot+[DarkRed,thick, mark=none, samples=200,domain = \omm:\omM] {sina(x)+sinb(x)};
       \end{axis}
       \begin{axis}[width=.8\columnwidth,
       height=5cm,
       yshift=-5cm,
       xmin=\omm,
       xmax=\omM,
       axis y line=left,
       ylabel= \textcolor{blue}{Amplitude},
       xlabel= position,
        smooth,
       ]
       \addplot[blue,thin, mark=none, samples=200,domain = \omm:\omM] {sina(x-4)};
       \addplot[blue,thin, dashed, mark=none, samples=200,domain = \omm:\omM] {sinb(x-4)};
       \addplot+[DarkRed,thick, mark=none, samples=200,domain = \omm:\omM] {sina(x-4)+sinb(x)};
       \end{axis}
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but I definitively wouldn't expect to write `sina(x-4)+sinb(x)` for the shifted addition, but `sina(x-4)+sinb(x-4)`...

Is it really the expected behavior? If it is, can the logic behind be explained, as I found the *good* syntaxe by mistake.

**Edit:** Another alternative syntax to get the correct result, maybe it can help someone to understand what's happening:

```
\addplot+[DarkRed,thick, mark=none, samples=200,domain = \omm:\omM] {sinb(\x-4) + sina(\x-4)};
```

Replacing the usual `x` variable in the `\addplot` syntax for functions by `\x` shifts as expected the function `sina`.

**Edit 2:** If in the definition of `sina()` or `sinb()` the name of the variable is changed, for example by `\y`, the expected behavior is back. By replacing the definition of `sinb()` by:

```
% fréquence double
       function sinb(\y) {
        if and(\y>0,\y<1) then {
       return sin(720*\y);}
        else {return 0;};};
```

then the expected syntax (`sina(x-4)+sinb(x-4)` ) gives the expected result.

Comment: If you have problems when summing sines, then you should ask on a math forum

Comment: Note that you test for 0 > (x - 4) > 1 in your functions, so x ≠ `\x` in the second example. If you use, for example, (x - 1) as `\x`, you get sin(360x + 360) for the first function and sin(720x + 720) for the second function. Thus, the second function returns a result that is shifted relative to the first one. Since you only add the parts from the functions where 0 > (x - 1) > 1, these two parts will never overlap. At least to my humble understanding ...

Comment: What I want to illustrate is propagation of a signal, f(x-ct) with or without dispersion in a linear medium (sin wave propagating at different speed in the dispersive case).  So it's ok to test for $0 > (x - 4) > 1$ in the second case for both "si during a time unit" functions, as i want the signal between 4 and 5, and 0 everywhere else (non dispersive case, both sin move at the same speed). That's what I obtained in the almost MWE, but I don't understand why the sinb function is shifted in the working-but-i-dont-understand-why syntax, as it as x as argument, and not x-4 as I expect.

Comment: Related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611793/pgfplots-x-vs-x, which is not entirely conclusive but it seems to suggest that `x` and `\x` are intended to be the same (so if they are _not_ the same then something strange is going on).

Comment: @Marijn Thank you. I added a comment to this question as an example where they don't behave the same. A colleague found another workaround, by changing the name of the variable I'm using by default, ```x``` in the definitions of functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely a bug. The argument of `sina` is assigned to `\x` internally (if you used that name in the definition) and this value seems to leak out to the `sinb` call. That is, the second call behaves as if `x` were the entire argument of the first call. As you already noticed, this strangely does not happen when using `\x` instead of `x`. I do not understand the reason for this behavior, but it is definitely a bug, so I [reported it](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1215).

I can, however, suggest an alternative: Use `declare function` instead of `\tikzmath`. It is recommended in the `pgfplots` manual as a best practice for conserving compatibility with the `lua backend` (as illustrated [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/664745/48973)), which gives you more accuracy and speed, and offers all of the functionality you need, I think. Importantly, it does not exhibit the same bug:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[usenames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [
      declare function={
        ommin = 0;
        ommax = 10;
        sina(\x) = ifthenelse(and(\x>0, \x<1), sin(360*x), 0);
        sinb(\x) = ifthenelse(and(\x>0, \x<1), sin(720*x), 0);
%        % or, a bit more compactly:
%        sina(\x) = (0<\x && \x<1 ? sin(360*\x) : 0);
%        sinb(\x) = (0<\x && \x<1 ? sin(720*\x) : 0);
      },
    ]
  \begin{axis}[width=.8\columnwidth,
      height=5cm,
      xmin=ommin,
      xmax=ommax,
      axis y line=left,
      ylabel= \textcolor{blue}{Amplitude},
      xlabel= position,
      smooth,
    ]
  \addplot+[blue,thin, mark=none, samples=200,domain=ommin:ommax] {sina(x)};
  \addplot+[blue,thin, dashed, mark=none, samples=200,domain=ommin:ommax] {sinb(x)};
  \addplot+[DarkRed,thick, mark=none, samples=200,domain=ommin:ommax] {sina(x)+sinb(x)};
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[width=.8\columnwidth,
      height=5cm,
      yshift=-5cm,
      xmin=ommin,
      xmax=ommax,
      axis y line=left,
      ylabel= \textcolor{blue}{Amplitude},
      xlabel= position,
      smooth,
    ]
  \addplot+[blue,thin, mark=none, samples=200,domain=ommin:ommax] {sina(x-4)};
  \addplot+[blue,thin, dashed, mark=none, samples=200,domain=ommin:ommax] {sinb(x-4)};
  \addplot+[DarkRed,thick, mark=none, samples=200,domain=ommin:ommax] {sina(x-4)+sinb(x-4)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: +1 Being on a bounty spree :).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Always nice, when there are related bountied quesions. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would be nice if you could fill a bug report on the [github project page](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots).

Comment: @cjorssen As I wrote (and [linked](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1215)) in my answer, I did report this. I wasn't sure at first if it belonged to `pgfplots` or `pgf`, since it seemed to be a `\tikzmath` problem but I somehow couldn't reproduce it without `\pgfplots`. I went with the latter in the end and it seems to be correct. (Someone else reproduced it without `pgfplots`, don't know why I didn't get there.)

Comment: @schtandard Thanks a lot. Sorry I missed you mentioned you reported the bug :-)

Comment: Thank you for the report and great explanation, I learned more than expected! happy to validate the bounty.