# I need help ploting an equation

Tags: equations, plot

I am trying to plot a function in terms of another one, but my code is taking too long and at the end i am not getting any plot.

The function that i am trying to plot is: i_c(U_c(x))

U_c(x) = 5+exp(-1266.77*x)*(-5*cos(deg(5508.55*x))+10.3*sin(deg(5508.55*x)))

i_c(x)=exp(-1266.77*x)*(6.3*cos(deg(5508.55*x))+1.5*sin(deg(5508.55*x)) 

```
%i_c(x)= exp(-1266.77*x)*(6.3*cos(deg(5508.55*x))+1.5*sin(deg(5508.55*x))

%u_c(x)= 5+exp(-1266.77*x)*(-5*cos(deg(5508.55*x))+10.3*sin(deg(5508.55*x)))



\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    title = {Verlauf der Kondensatorspannung nach öffnen des Schalters},
    xlabel = {t in s}, 
    ylabel= {$u_C(t)$ in V},
     xmin = -10, xmax = 10,
     ymin = -10, ymax = 10,
    xtick distance = 1,
    ytick distance = 2,
    grid = both,
    minor tick num = 1,
    major grid style = {lightgray},
    minor grid style = {lightgray!0.25},
    width = \textwidth,
    height = 0.5\textwidth]
        \addplot[
        domain = -10:10,
        samples = 200,
        smooth,
        thick,
        blue,] {exp(-1266.77*5+exp(-1266.77*x)*(-5*cos(deg(5508.55*x))+10.3*sin(deg(5508.55*x))))*(6.3*cos(deg(5508.55*5+exp(-1266.77*x)*(-5*cos(deg(5508.55*x))+10.3*sin(deg(5508.55*x)))))+1.5*sin(deg(5508.55*5+exp(-1266.77*x)*(-5*cos(deg(5508.55*x))+10.3*sin(deg(5508.55*x)))))};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: TeX isn't supposed to be fast at doing math. (although you can enable Lua floating-point calculation backend https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611573/pgfplots-strange-bump-in-tanh-function ) — if that doesn't work generate a table of values with another programming language and include in.